# Create a Wi-Fi hotspot on a Raspberry Pi (with RPi OS) through its USB port via a USB Wi-Fi adapter?

Tags: wifi, linux, access-point

I need to use the inbuilt Wi-Fi to connect to an Internet access point. In effect, the RPi should act as a router for all intents and purposes, a router that serves all of my devices. But my question is, is it even possible to do this (How can a single Wi-Fi card manage two connections)? Is any additional software (like drivers) required or does it work like plug-and-play? How do I configure the network (using shell scripting?)?

Comment: A single Wifi card normally does not support two connections. The answer is in the title of your question: use the onboard Wifi for connecting to the Internet, and a USB Wi-Fi adapter for the internal network (or vice-versa, or even two USB wifi adapters)

Comment: @Ljm Dullaart Yeah, how do I do that? What drivers do I need and how do I configure the Pi?

Comment: Have you tried to search for a solution?

Comment: If I use Google, I get many results for howto's; for example https://thepi.io/how-to-use-your-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-point/, https://www.instructables.com/Use-Raspberry-Pi-3-As-Router/, https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2021/06/11/how-to-build-a-raspberry-pi-router-step-by-step-tutorial/ .